# MySQL to JSON listing multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am currently working on a PHP script that encodes user data into JSON, as well as associated actions/events a user might perform. For example, some fields from the user data (defined in a 'USER' MySQL table) include the user's first and last name, website login, and points for certain actions they complete. In a second table, known as 'MAYDO', the actions performed by the user are stored (referenced by IDs), and include information such as what the user did (went to a Starbucks, purchased X, did the action between dates Y and Z, etc.)

My Question was, how do I go about referencing each element in my 'MAYDO' table and associate it with the correct user, in the form of a JSON list?
I want to have some sort of functionality like this:

```
{
    'USER' {
        'Name': 'John Doe',
        'Occupation': 'Farmer',
        'Age': 39
        'User_id': 1
     },
     'MAYDO' [{
          'User_Id': 1,
          'Maydo_Id': 1,
          'Event': 'Go to Farmer\'s Market',
          'When': '2015-10-13 16:30:05'
      },
      {
          'User_Id': 1,
          'Maydo_Id': 2,
          'Event': 'Sell chickens at the auction',
          'When': '2015-11-13 12:00:00'
      }]
}
```

Essentially, I want all the rows in the 'MAYDO' table to associate with their respective Users who performed them, and basically become the list for that User's JSON dataa (one JSON file per person). The code I have currently tested only takes the last entry from the 'MAYDO' table (in the event of multiple events), and so I wanted to get some insight into how to fix this. Any help or tips are appreciated. Thank you!

Current code (Encodes the User data perfectly; only encodes the last 'MAYDO' entry)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>USER DATA TO JSON</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

# Define the connection to the database 
DEFINE('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', ''); 
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'Maydo');

# Create a connection to the database
$connection = @mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$index = 1;
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = " . $index;
$userinfo = array();
$username = "";

$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1) or die("ERROR: " .      
mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $userinfo['User'] = $row;
    $username = $row['USER_NAME']; 
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM MAYDO WHERE USER_ID = " . $index;

$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2) or die("ERROR: " .    
mysqli_error($connection));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $userinfo['Maydo'] = array($row);
}

echo json_encode($userinfo, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to push each of the rows in `$userinfo['Maydo']` into an array. Here you're resetting `$userinfo['Maydo']` to the last row that's run, so of course you're only getting the last row.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it doesn't grab info from the MAYDO table at all. I tried this: `array_push($userinfo['Maydo'], array($row));`

Comment: `$row` is an array: `array_push($userinfo['Maydo'], $row);` And you need to initialize: `$userinfo = array('Maydo' => array());`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and please refer to this helpful link
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
  <?php

    # Define the connection to the database 
    DEFINE('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root');
    DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', ''); 
    DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'Maydo');

    # Create a connection to the database
    $connection = @mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $index = 1;
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE USER_ID = " . $index;
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM MAYDO WHERE USER_ID = " . $index;

    $userinfo = array();
    $username = "";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1) or die("ERROR: " .      
    mysqli_error($connection));

    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2) or die("ERROR: " .    
    mysqli_error($connection));

    $mayDo = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
          array_push($mayDo,$row2);
        }
        array_push($row,$mayDo);
        array_push($userinfo,$row);
    }

    echo json_encode($userinfo, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    ?>
```

Comment: With this solution, I don't get any output in the form of $userinfo. I don't think you connected $mayDo with $userinfo - can you please tell me how to do that from here? Thank you!

Comment: The idea pushing the array into `$userinfo` is the key

Comment: Thank you, it makes much more sense now. For the MayDo array, however, I get the array listed for all their actions, but the array name that stores the list of actions is 0 instead of 'Maydo', perhaps because of the empty array it's stored in. Is there any way to name the two arrays as User and Maydo?

Comment: Yes There is ,but if the fetch data for user is more than one user  or a multidimensional array you will be in problems, However if you wan to create something like that 

 `array_push($userinfo["User"],$row); ` 

 and
 `array_push($userinfo["Maydo"],$mayDo);`